# Merge CSV files into one EXCEL file with different sheets with Python

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

I have multiple CSV files and I want to move them to *one excel file with different sheets*. So, I am looking to add each CSV file to a sheet of excel. If there are 3 CSV files, it should be one Excel file with *3 sheets*, and sheet names must be the CSV file name.

What would be the best solution for this?

Comment: What have you tried so far and what problem you cannot solve? Check [ask].

Comment: I googled for a solution but couldn't find a specific solution so that's why positing it here since I don't have an idea how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd
import pathlib

with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:
    for filename in pathlib.Path('.').glob('*.csv'):
        df = pd.read_csv(filename)
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=filename.stem, index=False)
```